# Error: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I got this error when i run this method . can any one explain me what's wrong in the code . Below is my function code

```
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $uuid, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result=$stmt->bind_result($uuid, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt);
   // $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        return $user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: @JayBlanchard can you me any simple example of it

Comment: There are links in the comments which demonstrate the concepts.

Comment: @Anant [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) is a MySQL function. By quoting it `'NOW()'`, it would become a string, which would be invalid.

Comment: Why are you doing a `->bind_result()` on an `INSERT`? Your `INSERT` query does not return any results to bind. It should be used on a `SELECT`

Comment: It could be that, if the `unique_id` column is an AI (int), then you can't bind it on INSERT, AI will do that on its own. Or, you need to use an `i` instead of an `s` and doing `VALUES('', ?, ?, ?, ?,`

Comment: @AlienArtSoftware So, where are we with the question? You've been given an answer below but no green tick next to it or commenting. Not to mention what comments have been given you here.

Comment: @AlienArtSoftware ok, so the answer was accepted all of a sudden; why so? Oh, and I've done result binding on INSERT before (it's tricky), just so you know it can be done.

Comment: Sometime it happens friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The erro says that you have bind N variables but none fields, because it's an `insert` does not return value. `bind_result()` should use in selects statements.

To fix, remove this line:

```
$result=$stmt->bind_result($uuid, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt);
```

Comment: I've done result binding on INSERT before, so this may not be the complete fix.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i'll do a double but i think this fix the problem, 'for work' the insert should return 6 columns LOL i know is very very very weird xD

Comment: @rray No problemo. FYI: result binding can be done for an SELECT/INSERT, as I've written a script just last week as a matter of fact. It's tricky, but it can be done. ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- could you pass some referece? i never see it, in postgres is possible an insert return the 'auto-increment'

Comment: @rray You can insert into an AI'd column using a prepared statement, just as long as the syntax *(in MySQL)* is `(ai'd_column, col2, col3) VALUES ('', ?, ?)` type of thing.